# Twitter GET statuses/mentions not returning anything

Tags: api, rest, twitter, get

I'm trying to get a user's `mentions using the Twitter REST API`, but I'm not getting any response when I call.

I'm basically just trying to hit the URL they specify in the link I provided. I'm trying to get mentions by a specific user.

Here are the URLs I've tried, and none of them work (they all return blank pages):

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/mentions.json
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/mentions.json?screen_name=ludjanio
https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/mentions.json?screen_name=ludjanio&include_entities=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API end-point requires authorization through OAuth. Besides all that, this API end-point doesn't accept the parameter screen_name. Full documentation of this API end point can be found here, https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions
If you want to get the mentions of an entirely different person, there is no direct API for this. But you can do a search for @, this is how most apps do this.